# Open new tab/window and close old one

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Here is my current code, but the `closeWindow` function is executed before the new tab opens.

```
    $(document.body).append('<iframe width="500px" height="500px" id="pcl_frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>');
    $('#pcl_frame').attr('src', data['url']);
    $('#pcl_frame').load(function() {
        // Load page
        document.getElementById('pcl_frame').contentWindow.CreateCBTPlayer(data['code'],"new");

        // Close current windows after the above tab/window opens
        closeWindow(); // has a 2 second delay
});
```

Is there a way to wait for the command above to open the new tab/window first, then close the current tab that was used to open the new window.

Also I can't change the `CreateCBTPlayer` function.

#### Disclaimer

I know what I'm doing isn't very logical, but it has to be done to get around an old system I have to work with.

Comment: What type of element is '#pcl_frame'?

Comment: It's an iFrame (updated the post)

Comment: You need to be more specific, what exactly is that code for? Also, you are aware that `document.getElementById('pcl_frame')` would be equal to `this` in that context?

Comment: Maybe give the new window an `onload` handler that closes the old window.

Comment: Oh no, I'm still quite new to jQuery/javascript, thanks. The code loads data['url'], which is a url on the same domain, then when this url has fully loaded in the iFrame, I run the CreateCBTPlayer function from within the iFrame, as this is where that function is, this function then opens a new tab, at which point I want to close the current tab.

Comment: @Barmar, what would I put in the onload handler to close the old window? (as I can change the code in the new tab)

Comment: Are you sure `CreateCBTPlayer` is even executing? Did you debug?

Comment: `CreateCBTPlayer` must be executing as the new tab does open... and it no new tabs opens when I comment out that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure, but I think you can do something like this:

```
(function(old_window) { 
    $(new_window).load(function() {
         old_window.close();
    });
})(window);
```

The outer self-calling anonymous function is used to bind the local variable `old_window` to the current window object.  The inner function is a closure that captures that binding and closes the window. This closure is bound to the new window's `onload` event. So when the new window is loaded, it will close the current window.

Comment: See explanation added to answer. Sorry, but closures are hard to explain.

Comment: try window.replace(`yoururl_here`)

Comment: @Gel The OP wanted to create a new window.

Comment: Ah I see.. The title said, close the old one. I thought OP meant close the existing one which what I wanted to do.  So for me replace() works. @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you're trying to do, but I'm guessing you have to set the source after the onload function to make it fire properly, and since `load()` is deprecated and you're using the native object anyway, why not just do it in plain js:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.width = '500px';
    iframe.height = '500px';
    iframe.id = 'pcl_frame';
    iframe.style.display = 'none'; //note that not all browsers load hidden content
    iframe.onload = function() {
        this.contentWindow.CreateCBTPlayer(data['code'],"new");
        closeWindow();
    }

$('body').append(iframe).attr('src', data['url']);
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. Testing in IE8. I get an error of `Object doesn't support property or method 'CreateCBTPlayer'`

Comment: So what you're saying is that you're using a really outdated browser, and in that browser your CreateCBTPlayer function does'nt work ? Try just replacing `this` with `iframe`, and see if that solves it, otherwise the problem is your function, not my code.

Comment: Trust me, if I had a choice I would be using IE10, or better yet, Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Using `iframe` instead of `this` resulted in the same error. Any other thoughts?